# Does TimeMachine backup iCloud Drive files?

Tags: macos, icloud, time-machine

Does TimeMachine backup the files I have in iCloud Drive? I want to use iCloud Drive more for files I don't use a lot. But it is important that there is a regular backup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iCloud Drive is a folder located in the Library folder: `~/Library/MobileDocuments`.

This folder will be back-upped but there are a few strings attached to it:

- As long as the files are stored locally it will be backed up.
- When there is a cloud icon next to the file it means it's stored in the cloud and not longer locally. It will **not** been backed up.

Comment: It looks like the location has changed over the years. See: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/297593/362888

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does. Technically, the iCloud Drive folder is located here:

```
~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com\~apple\~CloudDocs
```

with `~/Library` referring to the (hidden) Library folder inside your user home folder. As Time Machine backs up all of the user’s home folders (except for some standard exclusions like Caches) it will also back up your iCloud Drive.

Comment: Do you know how to verify that the files are being backed up? When I do `ls` on the path to the backup driver and sub-folders I get this error: ls: .: Operation not permitted

Comment: Try to precede your command with `sudo` to overcome the permission issue.

Comment: I tired that with the same result.

Comment: Funny. Works here—even without `sudo`…

Answer (score 0):

Time Machine does back up files in your iCloud Drive unless you exclude them (in Time Machine settings). Even if the files have a cloud icon next to them (not stored locally), it downloads the file during backup and stores a copy.

Comment: "Even if the files have a cloud icon next to them (not stored locally), it downloads the file during backup and stores a copy." False.